# What is the shape group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory

I'm familiar with topology and category theory a little bit as well as inverse limits of inverse systems. I would like to understand the shape group better.

For example, one could describe the fundamental group as "mapping in loops modulo homotopy". What are the elements of the shape group? Are the elements equivalence classes of maps modulo some relation? Basically, I would like to know what the definition of the elements of the shape group is.

Can anyone help me out please? I'd be so grateful!

Comment: Hi Tyler, welcome to MSE. It would help a lot if you would extend your question to explain better what the shape group is-to the extent you understand it, or at least with a link to a reference-and if you would try to ask a more specific question. This isn't an appropriate place to ask for a broad explanation of a topic.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize it was a broad question. For example, one could describe the fundamental group as "mapping in loops modulo homotopy". What are the elements of the shape group? Are the elements equivalence classes of maps modulo some relation? Basically, I would like to know what the definition of the elements of the shape group is :)

Comment: I understand that if one has a category C and a dense subcategory D of C, so that any object X in C admits an expansion as an inverse limit of an inverse system in Pro-D. And I understand that if X and Y are objects in the shape category (C,D) then a morphism between X and Y is an equivalence class of morphisms between the expansions of X and Y in Pro-D. My question is, how does this give rise to the shape group?

Comment: Tyler, thank you for specifying your question in the comments. Please now edit your question to reflect those comments. This will increase the chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Where did you encountered the terminology "shape group"? It is not standard terminology. So we can not help you unless you provide a reference/link.

Comment: @Pece The OP meant to ask specifically about the "first shape homotopy group" aka the "first Cech homotopy group" but "Shape Groups" is the AMS classification MSC 55Q07. It's pretty standard to mean the n-th shape homotopy group if one uses the term "n-th shape group."

Answer (score 1):

Typing 'Shape Group' into the search field of MathSciNet yields numerous paper on the subject.  For instance:

Brazas, Jeremy(1-GAS-MS); Fabel, Paul(1-MSS)
Thick Spanier groups and the first shape group.
Rocky Mountain J. Math. 44 (2014), no. 5, 1415–1444. 
55Q05 (55Q07 57M05)

Fischer, Hanspeter(1-BLS); Zastrow, Andreas(PL-GDAN)
Generalized universal covering spaces and the shape group. 
Fund. Math. 197 (2007), 167–196.

And here is the first paper (chronologically) on MathSciNet which has the term 'shape group' in the title.

Sanders, Thomas J. Shape groups for Hausdorff spaces. Glasnik Mat. Ser. III 8(28) (1973), 297–304. (Reviewer: S. Mardesic)

Comment: Welcome to Math Stackexchange. The references are a good contribution, but I've downvoted this answer for its snarky tone - publicly reprimanding your own grad student isn't a good look, is it? Also, I believe Pierre Cagne (Pece) has finished his PhD, despite what it says in his profile.

Comment: This is a forum for answering questions about mathematics. Publicly berating your students for asking questions is entirely inappropriate.

Comment: Dr. Conner is a great advisor and brought up great points for me though :)

Comment: @TylerHills: If you say so. There are plenty of advisors and math professors out there who are not abusive.